# What is the most efficient way to compute new sequence from old in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

For example, there is a list:

`s = [1,2,3,4]`

from which we want to get new list

`s1 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]` (length was reduced).

How to compute this with the most efficient way in Python (e.g. map, generator comprehensions)?

*Update:* 
OK, this example was very artificial. Accidently, I'm trying to find the fastest way to compute new list from old. And it will be interesting for me to see optimal ways (minor memory usage, for example)

Comment: what is the logic for the transformed string ?

Comment: Are you always trying to get the average of the two numbers that neighbor one another?  If so you could create a new sequence if you wanted then loop over the old one to create the new one.  If this is not the case please elaborate.

Comment: try the different ways and time them.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Efficient by what metric? Memory use? Speed? Number of characters of source code? Number of expected bugs? Try finding a correct algorithm first, and then, only if it is too slow, trying finding a faster one.

Comment: @JonathanV Not always, it was an example. I don't understand how to construct more complicated functions containing indexes of lists for map. That's the origin of my question.

Comment: You should provide us with some attempt of your own, it would help us understand what you are going for. What are the rules for transforming the old sequence?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve in particular?  Maybe some pseudo code that shows what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The question you need to answer is what is your criterea for creating `s1`.  It's not clear how you arrived there from `s`.  Did you take the average of the neighbors as @JonathanV asked, or are you adding 0.5 to all elements then removing the last, or subtracting 0.5 and removing the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "minor memory use" you could use Twisted Meadow's solution but in generator form:

```
new_list = ((s[i]+s[i+1])/2.0 for i in xrange(len(s)-1))
```

Using () instead of [] will produce a generator, and xrange() will produce a generator for the range. [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) are like lists except they don't load the entire array into memory at once -- they generate the next value with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
alist = [(s[i]+s[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(s)-1)]
```

well, i dont know how efficient it is.

Comment: You need to make the division by 2 a float. At least for Python 2.7, otherwise the elements of alist will be integers.

Comment: Why not `xrange` instead of `range`?

Comment: @kigurai yes. you are right. I am using python 3.3. So I didn't notice the difference. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @aeset, ehhh, i am using python 3.3, so...

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the fastest way, if you have a large list, is the following:

```
import numpy as np
kernel = np.array([0.5, 0.5]) # convolution kernel
my_list = range(100000) # lots of data
arr = np.array(my_list) # make it an array
result = np.convolve(arr, kernel, 'valid') # convolve
```

This uses convolution in the numeric python package, which should be really fast. I would love to see if someone can find a faster solution :)

**Edit** Did some benchmarking, and for lists of size 1000+ the numpy version is faster than Twisted Meadows version.

Comment: It sounds like you figure out the OP's criterea from going from `s` to `s1`.  Could you explain what they are asking for?

Comment: I am assuming that OP wants the average of each pair-wise elements. Because that is the simplest explanation of the data I could find.

Comment: @kigurai You are right, thank you for your comment. A mark about reduced length wasn't occasional.

Comment: @kigurai Added two faster methods, one with numpy, one with numexpr.

Comment: Or simply `(arr[1:] + arr[:-1])/2` for another factor of three speedup, in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import numba

my_list = range(100000) # lots of data
arr = np.array(my_list) # make it an array

def numpyConvolve():
    kernel = np.array([0.5, 0.5]) # convolution kernel
    return np.convolve(arr, kernel, 'valid') # convolve

@numba.autojit
def numpyAdd():
    a = arr[:-1]
    b = arr[1:]
    return (a+b)/2.0

def numexprAdd():
    a = arr[:-1]
    b = arr[1:]
    return ne.evaluate("(a+b)/2.0")

In [248]: %timeit numpyConvolve()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop

In [249]: %timeit numpyAdd()
1000 loops, best of 3: 248 µs per loop  (about 380 µs without numba)

In [250]: %timeit numexprAdd()
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know of numexpr.

Comment: It's quite fast for expression of some size. It's a jit compiler so some overhead in compiling is necessary. but for large-ish data it will beat out virtually anything :)

Comment: Using the numba autojit decreased the numpyAdd function down to about 250 µs :)